# How to form a matrix or a table in python for multiple dataframes (overlap count)

Tags: python

I have come across a problem that needs to be solved with python.

```
dataframe 1 dataframe 2             dataframe 3 
SID UID     SID UID                  SID    UID
123 dog     456 dog                  789    monkey
123 cat     456 bat                  789    fox
123 fish    456 bird                 789    bird
123 horse   456 cat                  789    donkey
123 mouse   456 mouse                789    mouse
123 cow     456 fox                  789    cat
```

I've tried intersection of dataframes but it works well with only 2 dataframes. I have 26 dataframes in total but for example I have taken only 3 dataframes.

Output can be table of DF1 overlapping with DF2 and DF3 (similarly DF2 with DF1 and DF3) or a matrix like shown below:

```
    123 456 789
123 6   3   2
456 3   6   4
789 2   4   6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example how to print a matrix with all intersections:

```
dfs = {'123': {'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'horse', 'mouse', 'cow'},
       '456': {'dog', 'bat', 'bird', 'cat', 'mouse', 'fox'},
       '789': {'monkey', 'fox', 'bird', 'donkey', 'mouse', 'cat'}}

def matrix(dfs):
  print (' '*4 + ' '.join(dfs.keys()))
  for x in dfs.keys():
    print (x, end=' ')
    for y in dfs.keys():
      print('{:>3}'.format(len( dfs[x] & dfs[y] )), end=' ')
    print('')

matrix(dfs)
```

But you should avoid redundant calculations (everything with everything) by using combinations:

```
import itertools

dfs = {'123': {'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'horse', 'mouse', 'cow'},
       '456': {'dog', 'bat', 'bird', 'cat', 'mouse', 'fox'},
       '789': {'monkey', 'fox', 'bird', 'donkey', 'mouse', 'cat'}}

for x, y in itertools.combinations(dfs.keys(), 2):
  print('{} & {}: {}'.format(x, y, len( dfs[x] & dfs[y] )))
```

Which will calculate only unique pairs:

```
123 & 456: 3
123 & 789: 2
456 & 789: 4
```

Comment: Appreciate the help.. 1) i am not able to combine dataframe as you have done in dfs={..}.. note that my dataframe has rows in millions.. 2) also now how can i take this output of the print and put it in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

A trivial way is to build everything:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
ix = [df.iat[0,0] for df in dfs]
data = [[df[df['UID'].isin(dg['UID'])].count()['SID']
     for df in dfs] for dg in dfs]
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=ix, index=ix)
```

But this does not use the symetry of result. If you have a large number of dataframes or have large dataframes, it is enough to compute half of the matrix. Code is slightly more complex, but will be more efficient for higher dimensions:

```
dfs = [df1, ..., dfn]
N = len(dfs)
ix = [df.iat[0,0] for df in dfs]
data = [[df[df['UID'].isin(dg['UID'])].count()['SID']    # compute below diagonal
     for df in dfs[:i]] for i,dg in enumerate(dfs)]
data = [x + [0]*(N-i) for i,x in enumerate(data)]        # build a square 2D list
arr = np.arr(data)                                       # build a 2D numpy array
arr += np.transpose(arr)                                 # fill the upper part
arr += np.diag([len(df) for df in dfs])                  # add the diagonal
result = pd.DataFrame(arr, ix, ix)
```

In both cases `result` is as expected:

```
>>> print(result.to_string())
     123  456  789
123    6    3    2
456    3    6    4
789    2    4    6
```

Comment: i am not able to combine dataframe as you have done in dfs=[..].. note that my dataframes has rows in millions..

Comment: I cannot understand the problem. `dfs` is just a plain list and as such only contains references on the dataframes. You mean that you cannot load all dataframes in memory at the same time? If yes you should say it in the question.

Comment: appreciate help. i got the desired output but also i want 123,456,789 ahead of created dataframe (as shown in my question -output) so that my matrix will be complete...

Comment: I still cannot understand, the `result` dataframe has 123,456,789 as both columns and index and prints as expected.

Comment: if i export this output to a excel,i do not get index as is. So i was thinking to put the index as a column in dataframe  so that it shows in the excel output..

Comment: @shre: I still cannot understand. By default, both `to_csv` and `to_excel` export both the index and column names. Please show what you do , what you expect, and what you get.